# Messages Between NodeJS Servers

Tags: node.js

Imagine that I have 5 NodeJS servers running some random operations (receiving data for example - That operations imply clients connected with the server). Now I want to create a 6th NodeJS server. I want the 5 servers connected with this new one, and when a new client connects with one of the 5 servers, they will send a message to tell that story (to the 6th server). How can I share messages between NodeJS servers?

My attempt:
the 6th NodeJS Server:

```
binaryServer = BinaryServer({ port: 9003}); //Stream de Entrada

binaryServer.on('connection', function (client) {

  console.log(client.id);


  client.on('stream', function (stream, meta) {

    console.log(client.id +"||" +stream.id);

    console.log(meta);

    console.log(meta);

    stream.on('data', function(data){

      console.log(data);
      stream.write("Recebi-----> "+data);

    })   



    stream.on('end', function () { 

          console.log("end");
    });

    stream.on('error', function (error) {
          console.log(error);
    });

    stream.on('pause', function () {  
          console.log("pause");

    });

    stream.on('resume', function () {
          console.log("resume");
    });

  });

  client.on('close', function(){

    console.log("close: "+client.id);

  });

});
```

One of the 5servers:

```
binaryclient = BinaryClient('ws://localhost:9003');

//(.....)

binaryclient.on('open', function() {
    console.log("opened connection");

    StreamC = binaryclient.createStream("dasda");

    StreamC.write("Somethin like" + total_clients);

    StreamC.on('data', function(data){

      console.log(data);

    });

    StreamC.on('error', function (error) {
          console.log(error);
    });

  });
```

using [Binarjs](https://github.com/binaryjs/binaryjs/blob/master/doc/api.md#class-binaryjsbinaryclient-nodejs-and-browsers)
Is giving this error:
"Error: Listen EADDRINUSE" in NodeJS with server side code.

Comment: I probably think its not possible by the buit in of node js but i think may be you would need to write some api for it and share it between servers

Comment: "How can I share messages between NodeJS servers?" — There are loads of different ways (voting to close as off-topic since it is way too broad), a simple, obvious, but inefficient approach would be to listen for and send HTTP requests.

Comment: edited with a new approach

Answer (score -1):

On possible Solution Is In the answer. My error was very simple... Because I did code replicate I defined httserver in the same port, in the two servers. Thats why the error happens. Despite of all one possible way is using BinaryJS